# MVC 4 using jquery how to check if the model property has elements in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm passing in a view model that works with the CheckBoxListFor property and I would like to hide the checkbox section if when I repost to the page there are no check marks ticked. I can show and hide the check box section with no problem using:

```
$('div.KSearch').hide();
```

or

```
$('div.KSearch').show();
```

What I've been trying to do is check the view model which has a List which hold the information for the keyword model. Is there anyway to check if this list has element being passed in within jquery so that I can show or hide the section with something like:

```
if (('@Model.SelectedKeywords').length) {
    $('div.KSearch').show();
} else {
    $('div.KSearch').hide();
}
```

but this always shows the section. Any ideas?

Comment: bit confused..post your related HTML codes too..

Comment: It looks like you're mixing C# with Javascript.  `.length` is the method to check the length of an array in Javascript.  If you have a C# `List` then you would call `.Count`.

Comment: I tried the `.Count` before I tried the `.length` and that throws a null exception on Post if no check boxes were ticked which means I would have to check if the model exists first which gets me back to my original problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var len = @Model.SelectedKeywords.Count;

if (len > 0) {
    $('div.KSearch').show();
} else {
    $('div.KSearch').hide();
}
```

`('@Model.SelectedKeywords').length` is treated as a string length in javascript, and it's always positive (and true) ;)

Comment: This works with a little tweaking (I'll give it to you since it is mostly correct and put me on the right path). You need to add an `@if{}` to check if the model is null first then your snippet works (with the addition of `@:` to get you out of the C# code block for the  jquery to execute. Thanks!

Comment: `var len = @(Model != null ? Model.SelectedKeywords.Count : 0)` That'll do

Answer (score 0):

> Check MVC Model is null or not in jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var checkBoxCount = @(Model.SelectedKeywords != null ? Model.SelectedKeywords.Count : 0);
    if (checkBoxCount != 0) {
        $('div.KSearch').show();
    } else {
        $('div.KSearch').hide();
    }

</script>
```

I hope this will help.